# opencv videocapture hangs/freeze when camera disconnected instead of returning "False"

Tags: python, c++, opencv, video, camera

I'm using OpenCV-Python 3.1  Following the example code from here:
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html and using a http camera stream instead of the default camera, the read function in videocapture never returns "False" (or anything for that matter) when the camera is physically disconnected, thus hanging/freezing the program entirely.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://url')

ret = True

while(ret):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(ret)
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm experiencing the same issue with the webcam of my MacBook, when the lid is closed (i.e. cam not available). After a quick look at the doc, the `VideoCapture` constructor doesn't seem to have any `timeout` parameter. So the solution has to involve forcibly interrupting this call from Python.

After yet more readings about Python's `asyncio` then `threading` in general, I couldn't come up with any clue on how to interrupt a method which is busy outside the interpreter. So I resorted to creating a daemon per `VideoCapture` call, and let them die on their own.

```
import threading, queue

class VideoCaptureDaemon(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, video, result_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.video = video
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        self.result_queue.put(cv2.VideoCapture(self.video))


def get_video_capture(video, timeout=5):
    res_queue = queue.Queue()
    VideoCaptureDaemon(video, res_queue).start()
    try:
        return res_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
    except queue.Empty:
        print('cv2.VideoCapture: could not grab input ({}). Timeout occurred after {:.2f}s'.format(video, timeout))
```

If anyone has better, I'm all ears.